# Typescript - Array of [MyType<T>, inferred T] where T can vary per element

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-types

#### TL;DR

How can I make an array of tuples where the second element of the tuple is inferred from the first?

Here's the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBVAdgEygXigZwQS2QHMoAfKAVzQgDMCJUBuAKCYOAnmoEMBjaABXJhIwADwAVACJ5q1KBAAe7NNlgIU6LJVQ06qAHxQA3kyhmoyLgFsIALhz4izAL4s2HbnygB5MMDwA9sjYEtKy8koQKmpIaJgUVLTI9IYm5lCoMrQ85AA2oPZSWczpyQDuAOLWdlAARgEBuRBcyC4sPEG4GTRcecC+-p32-Fzw-ly5ogOBwYZYaeblVTb23LnYEAA0TK5M1JQ8g8hQ8JSCwhBiReGKyqiqcLGaCTpJKQAUpuZgQiLDv5dQll9Nt0gE-DNsMNRuNJtNOkDZPp9EwAJTGL5mcFHVRYby1ABWEEOADouNhsHhCMh3kZnJtutw+vDggzsZDUSVzB1go0ICTcgFCO8fhdgCTLDY2RDOiTMrI8Dl8iBpTiJRBKtVOTsWKBIFBziIAIxhORYADkzWwIHNpCg5psmXIVltZHNAAtRqhXfbFJAxubmHqBADgAAmU3xS3km12h30PDOn0er3JiAANzwuUD7U6wANoaN-zFokNlxNwPiCzMkpq5tFxvN22czCYPK6ZfDxZEpdDEcr80xFmq9nrfabO1bwYLYtNir6IERcluUXuMQ08W0umSBniAG1O0uQVBrtQALpT8DQOdK0DeagSCJ3VSduYnp+rl+h0QEagcKCIIYAD8AFQPYW5vIwTDTp2N4LmGEidh+0RIVgr77ienYMnByr3ohoaGBeLDvPsyCHDMUDvOi1YnGcobvJ2RoMkYGRZPOyqjn6HDALazjaukpzIJ2DGFsxrEKreICcQo-o8QySwjlACDkNAfFcmYgnCYxYnytkC7SbJTYWBqyw1MpqnakOmn0Z2YY6WxkmcZm2ZQGpVl0WKIlinZxjiXpHG+s5RkKSsSmnBZ6m0UJNl9vZEn6YFWbBSZinma5lnpAA9JlODugEeToKgARKe60DYNUUDkpV9TphALBZTl7b5g2lxQjOIg4aAe5nvuQ7ZekUAHqJvoydx5pnqC5j9ekQ3eQylpBRNfU5SSq2VaoVgtCAUAtcAqgBPAfnsf4ECqFVACSUBlC0wDLVARF3U1O2hm1sEOfB3W9Q1A2zca81cQGS3fTNtn-Ytk1mP1q0kutUCbcg227fth26cdeCnbDl3Xcgt3fQ933UAdlFPXuu0Mqjkk9QEchI9Rd3pITh3vE0+Z4PEAAMDBQGzohQAAzFzeAANRC3TwMDRpHkiCKoZxf5oDySloUAITK2zbni2Yrjfa4fFUQwQA) of the below code.

#### My situation

I'm using [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev) to open various Sudoku sites, read in the game, solve it, and move onto the next site.

Each site is represented by a `Puppet<TDiff>` where `TDiff` is a set of strings representing a site-specific difficulty name (if there is one).  I have a function called `runPuppet` which takes in a `Puppet` and some options, one of which is difficulty, and then performs the above algorithm.

(Sorry for the long code snippets.  I tried to keep them short as possible.)

**run-puppet.ts**

```ts
interface Puppet<TDiff extends string | undefined = undefined> {
   // ...
}

interface RunOptions<TDiff extends string | undefined> {
   difficulty: TDiff;
   newGame: boolean;
   // ...
}

const default options = {
   newGame: false,
   // difficulty is not defined
   // ...
};

export default async function runPuppet<TDiff extends string | undefined = undefined>(
    puppet: Puppet<TDiff>,
    options: Partial<RunOptions<TDiff>>
) {
    options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
    // ...
}
```

**sudoku-com.ts (for [sudoku.com](https://sudoku.com))**

```ts
type Difficulty = 'easy' | 'medium' | 'hard' | 'expert';

const SudokuDotComPuppet: Puppet<Difficulty> = {
    // ...
}
```

**websudoku-com.ts (for [websudoku.com](https://websudoku.com))**

```ts
type Difficulty = 'easy' | 'medium' | 'hard' | 'evil';

const WebSudokuDotComPuppet: Puppet<Difficulty> = {
    // ...
}
```

**main.ts**

```ts
(async () => {
    await runPuppet(WebSudokuDotComPuppet, { difficulty: 'evil' });
    await runPuppet(WebSudokuDotComPuppet, { difficulty: 'evil', newGame: true });
    await runPuppet(WebSudokuDotComPuppet, { difficulty: 'evil', newGame: true });
    await runPuppet(SudokuDotComPuppet, { difficulty: 'expert' });
    await runPuppet(SudokuDotComPuppet, { difficulty: 'expert', newGame: true });
    await runPuppet(SudokuDotComPuppet, { difficulty: 'expert', newGame: true });
})();
```

This code runs both puppets three times and is all working fine.

Now I want to abstract the code in main.ts to use an array of tuples: `Array<[Puppet<TDiff>, TDiff]>` where each element has its own TDiff.  This way I can do:

```ts
// needs to be fixed
type PuppetDifficulty<TDiff extends string | undefined = undefined> =
    [Puppet<TDiff>, TDiff];

(async () => {
    // throws compile-time errors
    const puppets: PuppetDifficulty[] = [
        [ WebSudokuDotComPuppet, 'evil' ],
        [ SudokuDotComPuppet, 'expert' ],
    ];

    for (const [puppet, difficulty] of puppets) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            await runPuppet(puppet, { difficulty, newGame: !!i });
        }
    }
})();
```

This throws four errors that essentially all boil down to `'expert'` and `'evil'` not being assignable to `undefined`.  This is because `Puppet` without a `<TDiff>` assumes that it's undefined, rather than trying to infer based on the arguments.

I've tried to use the `ElementType<T>` pattern:

```ts
type DifficultyType<TPuppet extends Puppet> =
    TPuppet extends Puppet<infer T> ? T : undefined;

type PuppetDifficulty<TPuppet extends Puppet = Puppet> = [ TPuppet, DifficultyType<TPuppet> ];

(async () => {
    const puppets: PuppetDifficulty[] = [
        [ WebSudokuDotComPuppet, 'evil' ],
        [ SudokuDotComPuppet, 'expert' ],
    ];

    // ...
)();
```

This results in the same four errors.

Comment: This really doesn't seem to be a [*minimal* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since there's so much code compared to the relatively short question.  Could you strip this down to the barest minimum that demonstrates the issue?  Or at the very least to something someone can just copy into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)?  My guess is that you could do what you want with mapped tuples and inference from mapped types, but I'm not prepared to answer without something I can test more easily. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I hadn't realized how long it was until I finished typing it all out, and then was too tired to simplify it.  I added the playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I have time to *fully* explain this, but as a sketch.. the basic idea is to make a generic helper function whose generic type parameter is intended to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) corresponding to the first parameter of each of your pairs, and then [map this tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to the actual pairs you are passing in.  The compiler should be able to use [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to infer the type parameter from the passed-in array, or warn you if you do something that can't be inferred.  There are all sorts of caveats about hinting the compiler to interpret a parameter like `["a", 1]` as `[string, number]` and not `Array<string | number>`, how to get the proper inference, etc, but that's the basic idea.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const puppetDifficulties = <P extends Array<Puppet<any>>>(
  arr: [] | { [I in keyof P]: [P[I], P[I] extends Puppet<infer S> ? S : never] }
) => arr as Exclude<typeof arr, []>;
```

And then I would use it like this:

```
  const puppets = puppetDifficulties([
    [Puppet1, "expert"],
    [Puppet2, "evil"],
    [Puppet1, "XXXX"] // error! not assignable to [Puppet<Puppet1Diff>, Puppet1Diff]
  ]);
```

Note that even though `puppets` is strongly typed, you lose type safety by iterating over it as if it were a regular array (iterating over tuple of type `[string, number, boolean]` will just give you elements of type `string | number | boolean`.  So the following doesn't give you any errors, but only because things are interpreted as unions:

```
  for (const [puppet, difficulty] of puppets) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      runPuppet(puppet, { difficulty, newGame: !!i });
    }
  }
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBVAdgEygXigZwQS2QHMoAfKAVzQgDMCJUBuAKCYOAnmoEMBjaABXJhIwADwAVACJ5q1KBAAe7NNlgIU6LJVQ06qAHxQA3kyhRkXALYQAXDnxFmAXxZsO3PlADyYYHgD2yNgS0rLyShAqakhomBRUtMj0hiZmqDK0POQANqB2UhnMZkkA7gDiVrZQAEb+-tkQXMjOLDyBuFA63DnAPn7tdvxc8H5c2aJ9AUGGWKnmEOWVdtzZ2BBMTsxM1JQ8-chQ8JSCwhBiBWGKyqiqcDGa8V16+gAUplBgQiKDX2chGfoADTvfy+KbYQbDUbjSbtf6yfT6JgASmMILB7TiXmqACsIHsAHRcbDYPCEZAvIxOQGdGhcHqwoI00H7bDIopQNpBeoQAnZfyEF6fU7AAkWazMjFBAnpWR4LK5ECS1lihYVazsjYsUCQKAnEQARlCciwACJGtgQKbSFBTdZ0uRLNayKaABbDVDO22KSAjU3MHUCX7AABMxri5uJVptdvoeEdXrdHsTEAAbnhsv7Wu1gHrgwafiLRPqzkaAXE5uKqqbhYbTRstlyOiXQ4WRMXg2Hy7N3lW7DXO-XNtmgrna2djfKengIKosMXwtdVABBeDwLggDtFpogRGvd7DeB2ADaAF0bUYoMeAJJQAhQADWEBA-jk-FPJ-4N9PNK-1-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)

Comment: Incredible.  Thank you!

Comment: If you've got a second, could you explain why we have to include `[]` in the `arr` type union?  When I remove it, it treats the elements as unions of each other, but I don't understand why.  Everything else I understand.

Comment: It hints to infer an array as a tuple if possible... see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) and the issue it's part of